# Is there any way to dump logs in Android Studio in such a way that they can be reused by the Android Monitor?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I love the Android Monitor because it allows you to click a link in the stack trace of an exception. When I dump the log, I lose all the formatting that would allow me to click on links in the stack trace.

When I dump a log, is there any way to reload the log into my Android Monitor so that I can still use Android Monitor as a debugging tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this in Android Studio.  In the Analyze menu there is an option called "Analyze Stack Trace" that allows you to paste a stack trace into it (or provide a log file) so you can navigate it easily.  If you already have it copied to your clipboard, it will even be pre-populated in that window.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This will help so much!